# Android Studio - how to add a preview for layouts I will inflate somewhere in my code?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have 3 Layouts:

**fragment_tag.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_stunde.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_fach.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView_raum"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView_fach"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView_lehrer"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want is that all the content of `fragment_fach.xml` were displayed in `fragment_stunde.xml` as a preview in the IDE. (fragment_stunde.xml should be displayed in `fragment_tag.xml`) I will inflate `fragment_fach.xml` somewhere in my code and I want that I see how it looks in the other fragment that I'm able to improve the design.

I tried to add `tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_fach"` to `fragment_stunde.xml` but this doesn't work.

Is this possible anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this to your root element:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Cheers

Comment: did that, but this still doesn't work. the namespaces are okay

Answer (score 0):

```
tools:layout="@layout/yourfragment"
```

Comment: it seems that this don't work. this shows still an empty layout. even when I'm adding hint strings. I also added `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`